# Query returns different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-like

I have 2 queries( i belive they must return same amount of rows:) ) :

1.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM myDataBase.myTable
WHERE CONTAINS(NAME, 'ABC')
```

2.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM myDataBase.myTable
WHERE NAME LIKE '%ABC%'
```

But in practice i have the following results(for example):

*for the (1.) query*

- first execution of (1.) query: **980 rows affected**
- second execution of (1.) query: **996 rows affected**
- ...
- N execution of (1.) query: **1000 rows affected**

*and for the (2.) query*

- first execution of (2.) query: **1000 rows affected**

So my question is: Why does it happen? What i'm doing wrong? :)

P.S. I'm new to Sql Server and and it's features, so i understand it's all my lack of theory, haven't found anything about this question, so decided to ask

Comment: Is the database currently in use when you are testing these queries?

Comment: hm, i guess it's not,because the only user here it's me, and i don't run any queries.

Answer (score 2):

CONTAINS is a full text predicate and looks for the word "ABC" in the full text index according to the current language's word breaker rules.

LIKE scans the column.

So LIKE would find 'XABCX' while CONTAINS would not.

Comment: Well, the code i wrote above is an example, in fact i am dealing with the addresses, wich are stored in the table like that: _NameOfRegion_ /_NameOfDistrict_ / _NameOfCity_ / _NameOfStreet_

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if it's names or addresses.  But to clarify, CONTAINS(NAME, 'ABC') and LIKE '%ABC%' are not synonymous.  Also note that full text indexes are populated asynchronously, so if the index was not up to date, that could be why you see the number of results creeping up as you repeatedly execute your first query.

Comment: > It doesn't make a difference if it's names or addresses. But to  > clarify, CONTAINS(NAME, 'ABC') and LIKE '%ABC%' are not synonymous.                                                     Yeah, thanks, i think i've understood the difference                                                        >so if the index was not up to date                                I've just finished executing of "Start Full Population" function(i guess that thing sets my index "up-to-date" or i mistaken?) And now _(1.)-like-queries_ seem to return constant result.

Answer (score 1):

CONTAINS works off of the Full Text Search engine.

It's entirely possible that the FTS indexes are being rebuilt in between runs of that query.  If that is the case then I would expect the results you are seeing.

So, either don't use FTS or change the FTS population schedule to something a bit more acceptable.